# Bright lights produce strange artifacts on Android

Tags: unity, android, lighting

I'm testing lighting on Android and I'm getting strange artifacts when the light is increased. I'm not sure if this is normal with Unity or a setting somewhere is unchecked.

The only light in my scene is a spot light. I have to increase the brightness of it so that it illuminates everything in the scene properly.

On Windows 10 (in the editor), it displays just fine. You can turn the brightness up all day long and everything will just appear whiter. On Android, however, once you reach a certain threshold (a really low threshold), the colors turn to an abrupt magenta, then dark cyan, and eventually black. Because I'm using a spot light, these colors appear as a radial gradient.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Turning the brightness down. Unfortunately, I have to decrease it a lot to avoid the artifacts meaning my scene doesn't get illuminated in the way that I need it to be.
- Changing `Lightmapper` from `Enlighten` to `Progressive` in the Lighting window. But what I think this actually indicates is compression and so is unrelated.
- Not specifying a Skybox material and using `Custom` environment reflections.
- Tweaking Graphic settings for each tier (I have double checked HDR is enabled both here and on the camera present in each scene).
- Switching to `Linear` color space (I was originally using Gamma). The idea was maybe the color space was too small so really, really bright colors couldn't be represented; however, it is my understanding that `Gamma` is much larger than `Linear` so I'm admittedly confused.

I have Googled this issue quite a bit and all I get are issues with emissive materials not emitting light and other unrelated light issues.

Here is what my scene looks like when a spot light faces a rectangular mesh.

When the threshold is exceed initially, it looks like this:

[image]

If you continue to increase the `Intensity`, it eventually looks like this:

[image]

Of course, the exact colors you see vary based on the actual color of the mesh being illuminated. In the pictures above, the mesh is supposed to be a medium-dark green.

Could this be a color space issue? Perhaps a device limitation? My device isn't exactly a super computer, but it isn't bottom-grade either.

Comment: Could it be related with the 32-bit Display Buffer on the Android tab in PlayerSettings? it says something about "use it only if you see banding"

Comment: No, it is checked. I tested with it unchecked, but now it produces a whole new problem! So I went back...and I still have my original problem.